# Autodesk Forge - DGN file element externalId

Tags: autodesk-forge

After converting a DGN file to SVF and querying an object external Id my result is formatted as an array of base64 string :

```
["MW1jMDktYmJ2X21zZC1kci1kbTMtbnMwNV9ubDEzLTE2NDcwNC1wMDItczMuaS5kZ25fMg==","NDkzOEY1NTdDMUJDRDdBREVEM0Q4RDAwMzk0NTY3NzNFMUQ1MzkxNw=="]
```

After decoding, the first item in array match the model file path

```
1mc09-bbv_msd-dr-dm3-ns05_nl13-164704-p02-s3.i.dgn_2
```

But the second element seems to be an hex number but I cannot figure out what it means:

```
4938F557C1BCD7ADED3D8D0039456773E1D53917
```

Is there a way to get the DGN ElementId from the externalId ?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Forge Model Derivative service tries to use some "reasonable unique ID schema" for each input file format. For example, for Revit files it uses Revit GUIDs, for Inventor designs it uses a path, for AutoCAD drawings it uses handles, for IFC files it uses IFC GUIDs, etc.

If the `externalId` generated for your DGN files does not contain the ID you need, you could try and look for it in the element's *properties*, like so:

1. Map the `externalId` to `dbId` (this is the simple numerical ID schema used by SVF), using the [Model#getExternalIdMapping](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Model/#getexternalidmapping-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) method
2. Retrieve properties of the `dbId` using the [Model#getProperties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Model/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) method
3. Check if the "DGN ElementId" is included in the properties

Comment: Thanks Petr for the reply,
Our first thought was to access the DGN ElementId based on element properties. Unfortunately on some case, the property does not exists on the element.

Comment: Does it mean that the ElementId is missing on objects where you would expect it to be available? If you're selecting the elements in the viewer, check the Model Browser - perhaps the property is available on one of the parents of the tree node that the viewer selected.

Comment: I update the first question to include a screenshot of my model. The element has no parent.

Comment: Thank you :) So again, is the "Shape" element supposed to have a DGN ElementId as well? If so, please consider sharing the DGN file with us (confidentially, we would only share it internally with the Derivative Service team) so that we could debug it on our side.